# JAR file not Running Properly

Tags: java, jar, runnable

I have created a runnable jar file that contains the following classes:

Main.class (This contains the main method)

Form.class

WrapLayout.class

The manifest file (Manifest.txt) contains the following:

```
Main-Class: Main
```

(It has a new line at the end)

I have created the jar file using this command:

```
jar cfm Organizer.jar Manifest.txt Main.class Form.class WrapLayout.class
```

The jar file is created, but when I run it, the command window opens up for a split second, closes, and nothing else happens. The file is a swing application, and I am running Windows XP on Parallels Desktop for Mac, but I don't think that matters. Does anyone know what's wrong?

EDIT: I tried running the jar file in mac, and I got this error message in the console:

```
Exception in thread "main"
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVerionError: Main : Unsupported major.minor version51.0
```

Comment: Run the program from a terminal window - see if any error messages are printed out.

Comment: The command to run a jar file is `java -jar Organizer.jar`

Comment: I want the program to be double clickable, also running it in the command window doesn't work; I get the same error message in my post.

Comment: The error message means you've compiled with a newer version of Java than the JRE you're trying to use to run it.

Comment: How can I fix it? (I use eclipse)

Comment: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVerionError class version is higher than runtime java version

Answer (score 0):

follow these steps an test:

1. Start Command Prompt. Navigate to the folder that holds your class
   files: C:>cd \mywork
2. Set path to include JDK’s bin.  For example: C:\mywork> path
   c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0_09\bin;%path%
3. Compile your class(es): C:\mywork> javac *.java
4. Create a manifest file: C:\mywork> echo Main-Class: YourMainClass >manifest.txt
5. Create a jar file: C:\mywork> jar cvfm YourMainClass.jar manifest.txt
   *.class
6. Test your jar: C:\mywork> YourMainClass.jar

Comment: Can you explain it in more detail? I don't understand step 2.

Comment: To define your jdk path. 1.5.0_09 may be another version of jdk.